# Integral points in smooth cubic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth affine cubic curve in $\mathbb A^2$ defined by $f(T_1,T_2)\in\mathbb Z[T_1,T_2]$ (of course $\deg(f)=3$ by definition), and
$$n(f, B)=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb Z^2| |x_1|\leq B, |x_2|\leq B, f(x_1,x_2)=0\}.$$
If we require $X$ has a smooth projective closure in $\mathbb P^2$ (Thanks for the comments of Prof. Silverman), are there any uniform upper bounds of $n(f, B)$? We allow the bound depending on $B$.

PS. "Uniform" means the upper bound doesn't depend on $f$, so Siegel's integral points theorem is insufficient.

Comment: Are you asking for an asymptotic (in $B$) upper bound?  Do you want upper bounds for "small" $B$?  What precisely are you asking for?

Comment: Yes, such bounds are available. Not sure what the state of the art is now but with the determinant method one can obtain $O_\epsilon\left(B^{1/3 + \epsilon}\right)$ with the implied constant independent of $f$.

Comment: I know what you mentioned in Salberger's papers. But I believe for smooth curves, we have better bounds.

Comment: I asked for a uniform estimate. Of course an asymptotic result is also preferred.